Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations for index.vue files
I modified my vite.config.ts so that it recognizes index.vue files as entry points.
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue', '.json'] // added line
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000
  }
})


Thanks to this configuration, I can do this
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent' // automatically imports index.vue

MyComponent folder looks like this
MyComponent
|
+---index.vue
|
+---Subcomponent1.vue
|
+---...

It works, index.vue is automatically imported. The only issue is that index.vue is not properly resolved. I'm getting following error:
Cannot find module '../components/MyComponent' or its corresponding type declarations.ts-plugin(2307)
Due to this error I cannot navigate to index.vue when I try to go to the definition.
Edit #1
Thanks to Estus Flask insights I was able to find a solution which does not require changing many things, just create your folder like this
FencyComponent
|
+---FencyComponent.vue
|
+---Subcomponent1.vue
|
+---...

and then add a index.ts file which import and exports the main component, like this
// index.ts

import FencyComponent from './FencyComponent.vue'

export default FencyComponent

Now you can import it like this
import FencyComponent from '@/components/FencyComponent' // it's a folder

The IDE won't complain at all.

This is a TypeScript error, give it a search online.

@kissu thanks, now I made the question more on point. I tried looking online and I found people with my same issue, but their solution didn't work for me

Feel free to give a more detailed [repro] for further debugging. Maybe give a try to a few tsconfig settings or otherwise try to import it with an index.vue suffix. If you're not too familiar with TS, you can also skip the TS check/usage in your components altogether.

@kissu I added a link to StackBlitz, but there everything works as it should. I don't really know why, though. Hope it helps debugging

You need to provide a way to reproduce, a demo that can't do this can't help. If the problem persists, you can reduce your project to "hello world" and publish to a repo. It's also unknown where the error occurs. If you see it in IDE only, it's specific to IDE.

The problem may appear in a specific environment or tool (IDE). What you're trying to do is know to produce unreliable and undocumented behaviour, both resolving a folder to index file, and and omitting .vue extension. Also naming a component index.vue prevents a component from inferring correct name based on file name at compilation time, this should be preferably avoided .
A trouble-free way to do this is to import a component as @/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.vue. It's possible to re-export a component in index.ts (also necessary if a folder needs to expose several components), but in this case this may require to import it as @/components/MyComponent/index for compatibility reasons.
A more reliable way to import from @/components/MyComponent folder is to provide components/MyComponent/package.json that maps its contents through main, exports, etc package.json fields, this is the way it's done in third-party libraries like Primevue:
{
  "main": "./MyComponent.vue",
  "module": "./MyComponent.vue"
}

This requires the explicit support from the tools and relies on the resolution of Node modules that is expected to be correctly implemented.
The support for TypeScript types in IDEs (specifically VSCode) is limited by their implementation and can be improved by providing components/MyComponent/MyComponent.vue.d.ts dummy type file:
export default import("./MyComponent.vue")


Could you provide an example of the "More reliable way"? It's not really clear to me what should be done. Then I'll mark your answer as correct

Can you explain which part you have problem with? You need to create file at components/MyComponent/package.json with listed contents, and then you're supposed to be able to import components/MyComponent/MyComponent.vue component from @/components/MyComponent path with no other additions

I did what you suggested, and it works. The component is rendered correctly even though it was imported using import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'. The only issue is that the IDE I'm using (VS Code) doesn't seem to like it, since it gives "Cannot find module '@/components/FencyComponent' or its corresponding type declarations.ts-plugin(2307)". Due to this error I cannot navigate to component declaration, which is kinda a pain...

This is always expected to be a problem with specific ide, unless proven otherwise. I checked, it's indeed the case, it doesn't pick types from .vue when used this way. I updated the post with a workaround. I expect it to be the problem of "vue official" vsc plugin. I'd suggest to report it to https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools in case you want it to be fixed

I opted for the second solution proposed since it does not require changing many things. I updated the question, thank you very much

You're welcome. Notice that relying on node module resolution and importing components/FencyComponent/index.ts as @/components/FencyComponent depends on the implementation of a specific tool (ide) and may have the same consequences. I already walked through this and had to use @/components/FencyComponent/index instead to fix this, but the same trick with package.json could be used instead to make it stable
